# Cannot change class objects properties when it is stored in an array, why not?

Tags: iphone, arrays, class, properties, sprite

Basically I create an array and add instances of my custom class to it. But when i try to access properties of the instances stored in the array, I get no response from the class. Btw, it works with regular instances of a class.

```
//This works:
Laser *myLaser = [[Laser alloc] initWithPosX:100 Y:150 node:self];

myLaser.sprite.rotation = 50; //This changes the sprite¨s (the sprite inside the class) rotation


//This doesnt:

Laser *aLaser = [[Laser alloc] initWithPosX:100 Y:150 node:self];

[Lasers addObject:aLaser]; //Lasers is a NSMutableArray declared in the .h

[aLaser release];

Laser *copyLaser = [Lasers objectAtIndex:0];

copyLaser.sprite.rotation = 50; //For some reason this doesnt work!
```

Does anyone know why it doesnt work? Is it a problem with using NSMutableArray?, my class is an NSObject.

Comment: Has `Lasers` being initialized? Does it only contain `Laser` objects

Comment: saw your comment just now, I voted it up..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see here is that `Lasers` is not initialized and is nil here.

You have to initialize `Lasers` somewhere (probably just before you use it or in your init method of your view controller). Use `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`.

Comment: Little comment : the convention is to use non-capitalised word for instance of classes and capitalized word for classes. I would then call `Lasers` -> `lasers`instead. Also you can name it `lasersArray` for more clarity.

Comment: wow, thank you, cant believe I missed that :-) I agree about the name.. Great answer!